# What does "saturate" or "saturation" mean in relation to functions?

Tags: terminology

I am reading: https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/mlp.html

And the author uses the term saturate a lot in relation to functions.  What does that mean?

For example:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It means that the function changes over some range but then changes less and less as it approaches a limit, the saturation limit. Much like a solution gets saturated and doesn’t take up any more solvent beyond a certain point no matter how much you put in. The sigmoid is a typical example – it saturates in both directions as you move away from the centre. Another example is $1-\mathrm e^{-x}$, which saturates to $1$ as $x$ increases.